# How do I make a panorama from multiple rows and columns?

Tags: software, panorama

I want to stitch multiple images — let's say nine images — but not to form a panorama, but to form a big square of 9×9 matrix into  a single big image.

I want to show both the tall and wide angle view. How to achieve this?

Comment: What you talk about is, from a technical standpoint, a panorama, so the tools you can use to achieve your goal can actually be the same you would use for what you call "a panorama". Some panorama tools may not be up to the task of stitching images on a grid (as opposed to a straight line, if I understood your question), but Hugin or Photoshop's photomerge should both do, even for compositions larger and more complex than what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've liked to use [Microsoft ICE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/ice/) for my stitch jobs. It is quite simple to use, quite automatic in its operations, and it is free :)

I did a quick stitch with some handheld shots covering an area of roughly 2½ x 3 grid of images. Total number of images for this was 11 shots. I was shooting over a high fence with arms stretched straight up. Result is not very nice, but suits here well enough.

**1)** MS ICE matches the images automatically. Just drop the lot on the working area:

[image]

**2)** Select your camera movement style. *Rotating motion* works for a grid of images:

[image]

Next, click on the **cube**-like button or select *Orientation* from Tools menu.

**3)** Select *Projection* from a dropdown menu. It is best to test them all. In my case Cylinder-horizontal produced an image I liked most. In the pic below it is still projected as Cylinder-vertical:

[image]

**4)** When satisfied with the looks, set the cropping, JPEG compression, possible thumbnail image if you want one, and scaling percentage.

**5)** Last thing is to click on *Export to disk*.

[image]

And here's what all this brought to me:

[image]

Comment: yes that sort of thing i was searching for

Answer (score 3):

Any image stitching end to end or top to bottom is the same as processing a long panorama.  I guess you could call it a panandtiltorama.  You are still worried about the same things, such as finding the common areas between images and correcting for perspective distortions from the change in angle.

If the software you use for panoramas doesn't support grids natively, forming multiple horizontal panoramas and then forming those in to a vertical one will accomplish the same thing, though software supporting grids may do a slightly better job as it can consider both the horizontal and vertical changes when making perspective adjustments.

Answer (score 3):

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) does it automagically, just make sure that the pictures have clear enough overlapping areas.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Autopano Pro 3.0 for stitching horizontal panoramas and it works very well.
So I would use Autopano Giga 3.0 for a mosaic of rows and columns.
The trial version is fully operational, but it does stamp a watermark across the image. 
A comparison of two versions is available at this link:
http://www.kolor.com/autopano-pro-giga-comparison.html

Answer (score 1):

make left to right stitch of the 3 images to get 3 set of panorama and then with this three, make the vertical stitching.

Comment: Are you saying this is the best way to do a grid panorama? The only way?