# How can I get a 12ft wide field of view at 3ft distance?

Tags: lens, focal-length, field-of-view

Is it possible to get 12ft wide image from a 3ft distance?

I am a beginner and have very little knowledge on the field of view of cameras.

I calculated that a Go Pro would need a lens with 1.5mm focal length to achieve this using a calculator on this page: http://www.tawbaware.com/maxlyons/calc.htm

A DSLR would need aproximatly 5mm focal length lens to achieve this.

Am I getting the correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A DSLR would need aproximatly 5mm focal length lens to achieve this.

Based on the "Dimensional Field of View Calculator" a 1.5x crop sensor camera would need a lens with about a 6mm focal length. A "full frame" camera would need a lens with a 9mm focal length.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 6mm focal length lenses are available?

Comment: @Safinn No, they are not.

Comment: Well, they are, but you won't like it; the Nikon 6mm f/2.8 fisheye runs $160,000 or so on the used market, it weighs a little more than 5kg, and the big fish bowl in front is about 9-1/4 inches in diameter and unprotected from knocks and dings.

Comment: Wow ok, so the solution then is to increase the distance.Lol.

Comment: Yes, going for a full frame camera and Canon's 8-15mm lens is the only reasonably-priced option -- assuming you can't increase distance. Back up far enough and any camera/lens will do the job.

Comment: Fisheye focal length is not calculated the same way it is for rectilinear lenses. The 6 mm lens you are talking about has more than 200 degree angle of view, which is much more than what OP needs. I did not do the math, but I believe normal wider fisheyes would cover it on a crop sensor.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that would work for *some* purposes (i.e. a single still image) is to [stitch multiple pictures together](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42418/how-do-i-make-a-panorama-from-multiple-rows-and-columns). Since you mention a GoPro, I'm guessing this might not be what you have in mind, but it's one possible solution to the question as stated, so it should probably be included...

Answer (score 2):

A width of 12 units in a distance of 3 units corresponds to a *horizontal* angle of view of 127°.

For a full-frame digital SLR with a sensor width of 36 mm, the corresponding focal length is 9 mm.

You may want to consider using a fisheye lens, which typically offers a 180° *diagonal* angle of view or even a 180° circular fisheye image.